# mongoose mode.findOneAndUpdate query not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this:

```
 var id = req.body.id;
var query = {'_id': req.body.id, 'site': req.body.location, 'content': req.body.services, 'updatedByCNUM': req.body.cnum};

ServicesModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, id, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
    return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
});
console.log(req.body.Services, req.body.location)
```

I am new to mongoose, and I am trying to do an update query. I basically have the ID of the document, so I want to find it, and then update it with the new values (all being based into `query`). How can I do this? This above is not working, it says :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

thanks 4 the help

Comment: Looks like `req.newData` is null or undefined?

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry, didn't give the updated version. I am trying to figure out what is needed in place of `req.newData`. is that the parameter in which I need to pass what needs to be compared to make the update? I.e, if I am comparing the `id's`, then do I need to pass that there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServicesModel.findOneAndUpdate(
{_id : req.body.id},
 { $set: { site: req.body.location, content: req.body.services, updatedByCNUM: req.body.cnum } },
, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
    return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var id = req.body.id;

var query = {'_id': req.body.id, 'site': req.body.location, 'content': req.body.services, 'updatedByCNUM': req.body.cnum};

```
ServicesModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id : req.body.id},
  { $set: { query} },
  function(err, doc) {
  if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
  return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
});
```

Note: $set replaced every data there before. to add a new data on the previous one you need to use $pull or $push. you can check the docs here